# Search field with Thickbox issue

Tags: search, thickbox

i have a search form which is shown with Thickbox inside an iframe. the problem is.. that after i click "search" the result page is shown inside the same iframe! and i want it to be shown in the main windows.

so, how can i.. post the string and close the thickbox at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can have the form in the Thickbox call a function in the hosting page, will can close the Thickbox and redirect to your result page.